# error: use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKSwitchContextDialog'

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Building IOS Unity build and during the xcode archive step it fails with the following message.

We have updated facebook unity sdk from 8.* to 12.*

Error messages

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKSwitchContextDialog'
```

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKSwitchContextDialog'
```

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKSwitchContextDialog'
```

Tried different versions of Facebook related pods like

```
<iosPod name="FBSDKCoreKit_Basics" version="~> 12.1" />
<iosPod name="FBSDKCoreKit" version="~> 12.1" />
<iosPod name="FBSDKLoginKit" version="~> 12.1" />
<iosPod name="FBSDKShareKit" version="~> 12.1" />
<iosPod name="FBSDKGamingServicesKit" version="~> 12.1" />
```